# Is it Possible to call PopViewControllerAnimated and PushViewController for single click event

Tags: objective-c, xcode

On a buttonclick action I want to destroy the current screen at the same time I want to navigate it to home screen instead of previous screen.
I tried to do that by Putting this code but didn't work.

```
-(IBAction)     sel_goback
{
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    Home1ViewController *HM = [[Home1ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Home1ViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:HM animated:YES];
    [HM release];

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If `self` is the top view controller, then by the time `popViewControllerAnimated:` has returned, `self.navigationController` has been set to nil.  Try this:

```
-(IBAction)     sel_goback
{
    UINavigationController *nav = self.navigationController;
    [nav popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    Home1ViewController *HM = [[Home1ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Home1ViewController" bundle:nil];
    [nav pushViewController:HM animated:YES];
    [HM release];

}
```

However, "home screen" sounds like something that would already be on your navigation controller's stack.  Maybe what you really want is something like this:

```
-(IBAction)     sel_goback
{
    UINavigationController *nav = [self.navigationController];
    while (nav.viewControllers.count > 1 && ![nav.topViewController isKindOfClass:[Home1ViewController class]])
        [nav popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    if (![nav.topViewController isKindOfClass:[Home1ViewController class]]) {
        Home1ViewController *home = [[Home1ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Home1ViewController" bundle:nil];
        [nav setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObject:home] animated:YES];
    }
}
```